# Inject Value into JPA-Table-Annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations, code-injection

I have an JPA Entity which I Would like to use for 2 Tables.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name_should_be_injected")
class MyEntity{
  // Implementation goes here
}
```

So I would like to inject the table name with Spring.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't pursue this line of design. It will add a completely unnecessary level of complexity to your solution, it goes against the JPA specification and intention and it will leave anyone else looking at your solution scratching their heads.

The proper way to accomplish this in JPA is with an abstract base-class and `@Inheritance(strategy=TABLE_PER_CLASS)` (see [@Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Inheritance.html)).